# UNIX_TIMESTAMP giving unexpected values in MySQL when time_zone set manually

Tags: mysql, date, timezone

I'm currently investigating the behaviour of MySQL dates and times with the clients and servers running in different time zones.  I am writing test scripts in order to test what is going on when I run with the client and the server in certain time zones and as part of that work I need to be able to control the session time zone.  I am having problems setting the time zone to the same one that my system is currently defaulting to, so that it behaves exactly the same.

I would like to set the mysql SESSION time_zone variable set so that dates are interpreted in the same way as when the time_zone variable is left as the default SYSTEM value.  When I manually set the time_zone to Europe/London I expect UNIX_TIMESTAMP to continue to behave in the same way as when the the time_zone is set to SYSTEM, because my mysql system_time_zone is set to being in London (either GMT Summer time, or GMT Standard time). Instead I am finding that the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function returns different values depending on whether the time_zone is set to 'SYSTEM' or 'Europe/London', as you can see from the following:-

With date set to 25th August in the UK summer time and MySQL server rebooted so that it uses system_time_zone = 'GMT Summer Time' you can see that the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function returns different values when time_zone is SYSTEM (i.e. GMT Summer Time) and when it is set to Europe/London:-

```
$ date; mysql --protocol=TCP -uroot -proot mysql  -e "show variables LIKE 'system_time_zone'; SET SESSION time_zone = 'SYSTEM'; SELECT @@SESSION.time_zone; select NOW(); select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 12:00:00');SET SESSION time_zone = 'Europe/London'; SELECT @@SESSION.time_zone; select NOW(); select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 12:00:00');";
25 Aug 2015 09:12:20
+------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name    | Value           |
+------------------+-----------------+
| system_time_zone | GMT Summer Time |
+------------------+-----------------+
+---------------------+
| @@SESSION.time_zone |
+---------------------+
| SYSTEM              |
+---------------------+
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2015-08-25 09:12:21 |
+---------------------+
+---------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 12:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                 43200 |
+---------------------------------------+
+---------------------+
| @@SESSION.time_zone |
+---------------------+
| Europe/London       |
+---------------------+
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2015-08-25 09:12:21 |
+---------------------+
+---------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 12:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                 39600 |
+---------------------------------------+
MyPc
$
```

With date set to 24th December in the UK winter time and mysql server rebooted so that it uses system_time_zone = 'GMT Standard Time' I still get the same results, and so the whether system_time_zone is in Summer or Standard time doesn't seem to make a difference:-

```
$ date; mysql --protocol=TCP -uroot -proot mysql  -e "show variables LIKE 'system_time_zone'; SET SESSION time_zone = 'SYSTEM'; SELECT @@SESSION.time_zone; select NOW(); select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 12:00:00');SET SESSION time_zone = 'Europe/London'; SELECT @@SESSION.time_zone; select NOW(); select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 12:00:00');";
25 Dec 2015 09:14:13
+------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value             |
+------------------+-------------------+
| system_time_zone | GMT Standard Time |
+------------------+-------------------+
+---------------------+
| @@SESSION.time_zone |
+---------------------+
| SYSTEM              |
+---------------------+
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2015-12-25 09:14:14 |
+---------------------+
+---------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 12:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                 43200 |
+---------------------------------------+
+---------------------+
| @@SESSION.time_zone |
+---------------------+
| Europe/London       |
+---------------------+
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2015-12-25 09:14:14 |
+---------------------+
+---------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 12:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                 39600 |
+---------------------------------------+
MyPc
$
```

My Windows time zone is set to Europe/London as you can see from the cygwin TZ variable:-

```
MyPc
$ echo $TZ
Europe/London
MyPc
$
```

My questions are:-

1. Why are the UNIX_TIMESTAMPs returned different when it seems the time zones should be seen as the same?
2. What should I do to set my time zone so that UNIX_TIMESTAMP (and everything else) behaves the same as the when time_zone is left set to the default SYSTEM value?

**Update:**

I think I may have answered my own question.  I have found out that GMT and UTC are *NOT* the same before 31st Oct 1971 as you can see from:-

http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london?year=1970

http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london?year=1971

(try the above links for 1972 and 1973 too)

This is because BST didn't exist in the summer of 1971 and so in that summer GMT was an hour ahead of UTC and then on 31st Oct 1971 the clocks went back for the first time and GMT became in sync with UTC.

So if I do the same test as I did above, but use 1973 as the year then I get the same values for the Unix timestamps (as expected).  This must mean that when I leave the time zone as SYSTEM MySQL is interpretting the date as a UTC date and so giving 12 * 3600 = 43200 but when I set the time_zone to Europe/London it thinks the time means UK GMT in the winter of 1970 which is an hour behind UTC and so midday Jan 1st 1970 is 11:00 UTC = 11 * 3600 = 39600, as you can see from the following:-

```
$ date; mysql --protocol=TCP -uroot -proot mysql  -e "show variables LIKE 'system_time_zone'; SET SESSION time_zone = 'SYSTEM'; SELECT @@SESSION.time_zone; select NOW(); select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1973-01-01 12:00:00');SET SESSION time_zone = 'Europe/London'; SELECT @@SESSION.time_zone; select NOW(); select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1973-01-01 12:00:00');";
25 Aug 2015 12:33:36
+------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name    | Value           |
+------------------+-----------------+
| system_time_zone | GMT Summer Time |
+------------------+-----------------+
+---------------------+
| @@SESSION.time_zone |
+---------------------+
| SYSTEM              |
+---------------------+
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2015-08-25 12:33:37 |
+---------------------+
+---------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1973-01-01 12:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                              94737600 |
+---------------------------------------+
+---------------------+
| @@SESSION.time_zone |
+---------------------+
| Europe/London       |
+---------------------+
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2015-08-25 12:33:37 |
+---------------------+
+---------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1973-01-01 12:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                              94737600 |
+---------------------------------------+
MyPc
$
```

To avoid this problem I will do all must tests from now on using dates *after* 1973, and just pity anyone who does have to deal with dates pre 1973 in MySQL. I wouldn't be surprised if this is a MySQL bug because it seems system time zone of GMT should map exactly to the SESSION timezone of Europe/London, but doesn't.

Comment: I tested with EEST (Europe/Helsinki) and it seems I cannot reproduce this behavior (mysql 5.5.41). So it would indicate that: either GMT and Europe/London are different somehow, or it's a problem with your MySQL version or your setup (cygwin seriously?).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Think I may have answered my own question after more research.  See edit to question above.

Comment: Is the edit above your final answer, or an intermediate one? If it is a solution, would you move it to an answer, and self-accept? Thanks! (We like a clean separation between Q & A here, mainly for SEDE query and API users, but it's also nice to mark things as resolved).